# Inheritance in C++ and expected behavior

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm working on an assignment involving 4 classes and diamond inheritance. I've based all my answers on an assumption that may or may not be correct.

The diamond hierarchy is like this:

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
  \ /
   D
```

and the code looks like this:

```
class A
{
private:
   string s;
public: 
   A(string s);
   virtual ~A;
   virtual void set(string s);
   virtual string get();
};

class B : public virtual A
{
public:
 void set(string s);
 string get();
}

class C : public virtual A
{
public:
  void set(string s);
}

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
  void set(string s);
}
```

Suppose I have a pointer that looks like this:`C *obj = new D();`

If get is called on obj, the pointer will actually end up looping back to D and then invoke B's get method. A C object alone would end up invoking A's get method. Assuming B and A's get methods return different results, which result would be expected?

Comment: What do you mean by "behave"?

Comment: Well invoking get on the obj pointer will result in B's get being called. Invoking get on a C object alone would result in A's get being called. If these two situations end up with different results, would it be expected to get the first result or second result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided unfortunately won't compile as is.
We can create a similar example and just try it:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

struct A
{
  virtual char const * get() {return "a";};
  virtual ~A() = default;
};

struct B : public virtual A
{
  char const * get() override {return "b";};
};

struct C : public virtual A
{
  //char const * get() override {return "c";};
};

struct D : public B, public C
{
  //char const * get() override {return "d";};
};

int main()
{
  A* a = new A();
  B* b = new B();
  C* c = new C();
  C* d = new D();
  printf("%s\n", a->get());
  printf("%s\n", b->get());
  printf("%s\n", c->get());
  printf("%s\n", d->get());
  delete a;
  delete b;
  delete c;
  delete d;
}
```

which gives:

```
a
b
a
b
```

isocpp calls this [delegating to a sister class](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-delegate-to-sister)

As `B` and `C` both virtually inherit `A`, there is only a single instance of `A`, therefore in the virtual table, when `B` overrides an implementation of `A`, only a single member overrides `get` and this becomes also overridden for `D`.

Should you also uncomment the the `get` method in `C`, then we would get:

```
virtual.cc:19:8: error: no unique final overrider for 'virtual const char* A::get()' in 'D'
   19 | struct D : public B, public C
      |
```

However, further modifying the example and also uncommenting the `get` in `D` would make the code compile again. Now returning:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 1):

It will act like a `D` object.

Just like with single inheritance, it acts like the class that was created (not what the pointer to it is).